# SMS/Call log backup utilities not saving everything

Tags: samsung, backup

I have had a very frustrating experience in swapping over from one Android to another. As I had done with my previous transfer many years back, got the phone connected to the PC with developer mode and used ADB to take an `-all` backup, but upon restoring it on my new phone my ordeal started.

First Firefox on the new phone didn't have any of my open tabs, nor history, and after a bit of research, found that it has been built with the flag `android:allowBackup="false"` set [solving the corruption that I understand can occur when Android restores Firefox data from the cloud, but also disables local ADB backups](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1190375). I could find no other way to backup not only currently open pages in tabs, but also the history of those tabs - Firefox sync only recovers current page, not that tab's history.

Several other problems, some also having that same `android:allowBackup="false"` flag set, have had their data been copied at great time expense for either finding a solution, or manually copying the data.

Now I have struck a wall when trying to backup ALL call logs and SMS messages. Find below details of the discrepancies:

**On Source Device (Samsung SM N915A):**

`20` Conversations in "Messages" app (could find no way to see how many individual messages this includes)
`204` SMS's reported as being backed up via [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en)

`529` call details in "Contacts" app (which launches when I click the phone icon on the home screen), found by clicking the "Select" option in the ... dropdown and clicking the all button
`487` call details reported as being backed up via [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en)

**On Destination Device (Samsung SM G955U):**

`204` SMS's showing in [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en)'s backup of old phone
`17` Conversations in "Messages" App (after restore using above app and backup)

`487` call details showing in [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore&hl=en)'s backup of old phone
`363` call details in "Phone" App (after restore using above app and backup)

I have also tried [SMS Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobi.infolife.smsbackup&hl=en), [Super Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.idea.backup.smscontacts&hl=en), and [Helium](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup&hl=en) all with varying (by not complete) numbers of SMS's/Call details claiming as being on the source device and then restored on the destination device. Still further other apps have at least one commentor saying that MMS/Advanced messages are not saved using that app. I have not tried to figure out whether all the messages missing from the backup and what then gets restored are either of these, but at least the first few I looked at didn't seem to be. Regardless...

...Does *anybody* know of a way to get ALL of the SMS's and Call Details off the old phone?

*Footnote - Yes, I am seriously considering rooting the new phone before I accumulate any more data that I will need to deal with upon the next switch - Why phone manufacturers didn't allow, but not make obvious, users to be able to elevate themselves to root is well beyond me!*